# qplot not showing anything on my plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

hello I have been trying to use qplot to plot this data.frame

```
print(Data)
    partition     axis1     axis2
V1      Alpha  0.064989 -0.093558
V2       Beta -0.065058  0.009540
V3      Delta  0.100572 -0.081021
V4        Zed -0.152011  0.057507
V5      Alpha -0.039480 -0.020070
V6       Beta  0.044027 -0.055642
V7     Catsup -0.149427  0.038032
V8        Zed  0.133783 -0.021328
V9        Zed -0.014662 -0.029677
V10     Alpha -0.094468  0.002095
V11      Beta  0.090668 -0.033317
```

I am trying to use this code to plot by the axis and color by group

```
qplot(x="axis1", y= "axis2", data = taxi, color= "partition)
```

But nothing shows up at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to quote column names in ggplot or qplot.  There is something like an implicit `with` or `attach` that lets you refer to columns just like they were already defined as variables in your namespace.

```
qplot(data=taxi, x=axis1, y=axis2, color=partition)
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like it would work but qplot still isn't showing anything. It doesn't even replace the previous plot. [edit] I have to say print(qplot)) Thanks very much.

Comment: Only if you're not telling us the whole story!  If you have a ggplot call in a function, you certainly need to call `print` on it.

Comment: That was it. The previous ggplot was from an earlier part that I forgot to delete. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Justin solution is the way you go: No need to quote aes in ggplot2. But using `aes_string`, you can get the same the results with variables quoted:

```
ggplot(data = taxi) +
 geom_point(aes_string(x="axis1", y= "axis2", color= "partition"))
```

This can be useful for example,  if you wrap the ggplot call within a function for example...